# subscribing to system blogs

Tags: ektron

I have a 8.0.2SP1 site with a system blog.  The client wants to know what the subscribe button does but I can't find a description in the documentation.  Right now when someone clicks to subscribe, they get an option for all posts or all comments -- that part makes sense but it seems to do nothing. The client is expecting an email if a new post is added.  I can see in the documentation how community blogs work (by default it updates activity feed).  I can find in the  profile settings where you can specify delivery method for Group blogs and Colleague blogs.  But no settings for system blogs.

Q: What does subscribing to a system blog do?

Q: Are there profile-level settings for how the system handles notifications for system blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to a blog will alert someone when a new post has been made. Subscribing to a specific post will allow the user to be notified if comments have been posted. These settings assume that you have setup an smtp server (relay) in your web.config. Under the hood there's no major differences between a blog you create under a regular folder, or a group/user. For setting the alerts on the root level blogs you should see a "web alerts" tab under the blog's properties

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  Apparently the web alerts were never configured on the site but this definitely put me in the right direction.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing the web alerts and configuring the blog to use them.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks a ton!